# FreeSwitch voice delay on Android

Tags: sip, freeswitch, sipdroid

Currently, I am building mVoIP service for Android. I chose FreeSwitch as a SIP server, and there is no problem talking through PC. However, all Android open source make voice delay. Here are data we faced so far.

Case 1 - FreeSwitch + PC

```
FreeSwitch 1.2 Stable version
Linux CentOS 6.5
Xlite Softphone for PC Windows8 
Voice delay - less than 50ms
```

Case 2 - FreeSwitch + Android Sipdroid

```
FreeSwitch 1.2 Stable version
Linux CentOS 6.5
Sipdroid for Android 
Voice delay - 80 ~ 200 ms
```

Case 3 - FreeSwitch + Android Csipsimple

```
FreeSwitch 1.2 Stable version
Linux CentOS 6.5
Csipsimple for Android
Voice delay - 150 ~ 400 ms
```

Case 4 - FreeSwitch + Android SipDroid ==> PC

```
FreeSwitch 1.2 Stable version
Linux CentOS 6.5
Sipdroid for Android
Xlite Softphone for PC Windows8 
Voice delay - 50 ~ 100 ms
```

Some of Android mVoIP applications, such as Skype, make less than 50ms voice delay. We've tried many SIP open sources for Android, but all of them make horrible delay. We are looking for a open source that make less than 50ms for Android. Is there someone who can solve this issue? Thank you.

Is it maybe Android device is slow to encode and decode audio sound?

Answer (score 2):

it's a known problem with CentOS 6. You need to choose a different distro (Debian works fine with me)
http://wiki.freeswitch.org/wiki/Download_%26_Installation_Guide#Release.28es.29_6_and_Later

Comment: Have you tried on your FreeSwitch server with Sipdroid Android application? Was it fine? no delay?

Comment: I use Zoiper, but as far as I remember, sipdroid was also working fine

Comment: I installed FreeSwitch on Debian and CentOS 5.X. It still making sound delay like 100ms.. What do you mean working fine? Was it fine like cellular phone? no delay?

Comment: I also checked Zoiper, but it makes 100ms delay too.

Comment: what kind of a host is this? FreeSWITCH is usually working fine, even inside a VPS

Comment: It is Amazon Web Service C3 server. Now.. I believe Android is slow to encode and decode codec.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22626072/android-audio-codec-encoding-decoding-delay

Comment: well, last Saturday I was talking from Galaxy S3 and Moto G, without any problems. Such a big delay would be noticeable, but I was talking like on a normal phone.

Comment: I have a Galaxy S3. We tried under wifi network and 4G LTE network. It was same.

Comment: you can try reaching me via skype:ssinyagin or jabber: ssinyagin@swissjabber.ch but I have very limited reachability during european evening time